# How to use AAC ViewModel with native Activities/Fragments?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

Looks like ViewModelProviders.of() needs a FragmentActicity or a support.v4. Fragment to be passed in. In my situation I have a library that gives activity which extends from app Activity, so I can not use support one.
While AAC were unstable we needed to implement LifecycleOwner, is there something similar now?
Any ideas will be very helpful :)